# How can i override the save() method in admin page

Tags: python, django, admin

It maybe look like a simple question, but i been struggling for weeks now, I want to override the save method in admin page, for a model name `Transaction` that I created, I want to `pre_save` each transaction by groups.

Lets say for example I have created 2 groups (Test1, Test2) and I assigned users to each group, and a user from group Test1 made a transaction and saved it.

I want all users from Test1 group to see the transaction and modify it, but not Test2 groups members. I override save method and queryset method, but yet it still not working. any ideas ? here is my code
models.py

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
income_period_choices = (('Weekly', 'Weekly'), ('Fortnightly',
                                                'Fortnightly'))
chp_reference = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
rent_effective_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
income_period = models.CharField(max_length=11,
                                choices=income_period_choices,
                                null=True,
                                blank=True)
property_market_rent = models.DecimalField(help_text='Weekly',
                                        max_digits=7,
                                        decimal_places=2,
                                        null=True,
                                        blank=True)
```

admin.py

```
class TransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['chp_reference','familymember__name']
    inlines = [FamilyGroupInline,FamilyMemberInline]

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
       obj.user = request.user
       super().save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        qs = super().get_queryset(request)
        if request.user.is_superuser
            return qs
        return qs.filter(group__in=request.user.groups.all())
```

yet im trying to save a transaction for example logged in as a user from Test1 group, i still cant see the transaction nor any other transactions, butofc as a superuser i can access all.
and here a snippet of a message appears each time i try to add a new transaction :
[snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10hQd.png)

Comment: `obj.user` likely is a `user`, so it is not clear to me how you can assign `request.user.groups`. Can you share the relevant models and explain *what* you aim to do?

Comment: i edited the question with models and more specifications, and thanks for your interest to help! really appreciate @Willem Van Onsem

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding, you could use a decorator:

```
def hello(function):
  function()
  print('hello')

@hello
def dog():
  print('woof!')
```

It's like running `hello(dog)`. Running this script prints:

```
woof!
hello
```

So instead of `hello`, you write a `pre_save` decorator that does whatever you need!

More on decorators [here](https://realpython.com/primer-on-python-decorators/).

Comment: ive updated the question again, what im trying to understand is how to access the groups in admin based on the users, so that i can override the save method for each transaction made by a user in a certain group

Comment: Groups are stored in the database. If you want different results for different users in different groups, you'll have to write each result and inside the decorator, check the user's group and pass the result of that to `save`, in the line where I called `function()` inside the definition of `hello`.